# Heteroscedastic GLMM in lme4

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects

I am trying to fit a Poisson regression model with random effects using lme4. My response variable Y represents frequencies in a two way table but I am only interested in the impact of a covariate over the interactions (the alpha_aj terms of the loglinear representation of the table Y), therefore the design matrix includes fixed effects for each row and column that are not of interest in my case.

I would like to include cell-specific random effects with column-specific variances. However, when using glmer, the estimated variance component of the first column I declare in the model is always zero, as if some multicollinearity was present. I cannot see why this is happening, in particular, because when assuming just one common variance, the predicted random effects don't seem to be constrained in any way. Any help would be much appreciated.

An example of my data is:

```
A <- 26 #number of rows 
J <- 3 #number of columns
y <- c(3117, 2426, 3048, 2830, 5151, 5399, 3331, 4631, 4419, 4434, 4356, 2161,
     6057, 3154, 5250, 4209, 2880, 4193, 5017, 7642, 3977, 5605, 4362, 5785,
     4044, 7259, 345,  371, 324,  393,  406,  303,  253,  284,  627,  520, 
     296,  428,  589,  381,  723,  506, 382,  825, 481,  572,  446,  486,
     603,  682,  526,  549, 1967, 1803, 1811, 1924, 1778, 1508, 1387, 1325,
     2259, 1737, 1209, 1699, 2247, 1463, 2548, 1469, 1504, 2610, 1703, 2444,
     1984, 1742, 2365, 2653, 1984, 2749)
x <- c(0.02, -0.26,  0.00, -0.20,  0.15,  0.21,  0.18,  0.22, -0.05,  0.06,
     0.28, -0.19, -0.02,  0.07, -0.15,  0.05, -0.04, -0.19,  0.13,  0.06,
     0.02,  0.08, -0.19, -0.19, -0.08,  0.05, -0.17,  0.13, -0.12,  0.10,
     -0.12, -0.05, -0.11, -0.06,  0.07, -0.01,  0.01,  0.06,  0.05, -0.13,
     0.15,  0.00, -0.09,  0.09, -0.04, -0.03, -0.05,  0.00,  0.13,  0.15,
     0.04,  0.01,  0.15,  0.14,  0.12, 0.10, -0.03, -0.17, -0.06, -0.16,
     -0.02, -0.05, -0.29,  0.13, -0.03,  0.06, 0.00, -0.05,  0.13,  0.11,
     -0.09, -0.03,  0.03, -0.08,  0.06,  0.05,  0.04, -0.06)
```

The table Y is stacked by columns. To define the design matrix I use,

```
zg <- kronecker(matrix(1,J,1),diag(A))  #area specific fixed effects
zl <- rbind(kronecker(diag(2),matrix(1,A,1)),matrix(-1,A,J-1)) #column specific fixed effects
z <- cbind(zg,zl,x)
```

The model with common variance can be fitted using

```
library(lme4)
id <- seq(1,A*J)
model1 <- glmer(y ~ -1+z + (1|id),family = "poisson")
refit(model1)
```

To fit the model with column-specific variance components I am using:

```
col <- kronecker(diag(3),matrix(1,A,1))
model2 <- glmer(y ~ -1+z +  
        (-1+col[,1]|id) + (-1+col[,2]|id)+(-1+col[,3]|id) ,family = "poisson")
refit(model2)
```

I get the results:

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name     Std.Dev.
 id     col[, 1] 0.0000  
 id.1   col[, 2] 0.1973  
 id.2   col[, 3] 0.1231
```

As you can see, the estimated variance component for col1 is zero. If I change the order I'm using to declare the predictors,

```
model3 <- glmer(y ~ -1+z +  
        (-1+col[,2]|id) + (-1+col[,3]|id)+(-1+col[,1]|id) ,family = "poisson")
refit(model3)
```

Now is the second column the one that get a variance component estimate in zero:

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name     Std.Dev.
 id     col[, 2] 0.0000  
 id.1   col[, 3] 0.1422  
 id.2   col[, 1] 0.1861
```

From the definition of the model, I don't see why I couldn't have column-specific variances for the three columns. I guess I am missing something, thanks in advance for any hint!

EDITED (2)!!!

Using the initial data, I try to understand if there is any reason why the variances should be constrained. I fit the model using MCMCglmm:

```
model0 <- glm(y ~ -1+z ,family = "poisson")
prior <- list(B = list(mu=model0$coefficients,V=summary(model0)$cov.unscaled))
data <- data.frame(y,z,col,id)
data$column <- data$X1+2*data$X2+3*data$X3

library(MCMCglmm)
model3  <- MCMCglmm(y~-1+V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8+V9+V10+V11+V12+V13+V14+V15+V16+
        V17+V18+V19+V20+V21+V22+V23+V24+V25+V26+V27+V28+x, 
        random= ~idh(1):id, data = data, family="poisson", 
        rcov = ~idh(1):column,
        pr=TRUE, prior=prior,
verbose=TRUE, DIC=TRUE, singular.ok=FALSE, saveX=TRUE,
saveZ=TRUE, saveXL=TRUE, slice=FALSE, ginverse=NULL, 
nitt=50000, thin=10, burnin=10000)

std.dev <- c(sqrt(sum((model3$Sol[,-c(1:(A+J))]^2)[,1:A])/(nrow(model3$Sol)*A)),
sqrt(sum((model3$Sol[,-c(1:(A+J))]^2)[,(A+1):(2*A)])/(nrow(model3$Sol)*A)),
sqrt(sum((model3$Sol[,-c(1:(A+J))]^2)[,(2*A+1):(3*A)])/(nrow(model3$Sol)*A)))
```

The estimated column-specific variance components are:

[1] 0.05413170 0.13366658 0.08073213

I still don't see why I shouldn't use column-specific variances when fitting with lme4. 
I am thinking that there is some checking that lme4 is performing before fitting the model that ends up by setting that variance component in zero.  Does anybody know another way to specify such a model in lme4?

Many thanks for any hint!

Comment: Guessing that this *might* simply be a case of having insufficient power, in which case one or more of the random effects variances is likely to be estimated as zero.  Does the problem go away if you simulate a problem of larger dimensions (more observations and more levels of the random effects)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Ben.  I just edited my question including another dataset (50x5) but the problem persists. It seems to me like there is some checking that glmer is doing whose result is setting that variance component in zero, however, I have no more information respect to this. Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: I will have to think about this some more.  I think the problem is with the multicollinearity of `col` (i.e. the row sums of `col` are all equal to 1), but I can't at the moment state precisely why this is an issue.  This might turn into a [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) question, because I think the issue is really one of model formulation rather than estimation ...

Comment: Just added a piece of code to fit the model using MCMCglmm. I don't think that there is a problem with the formulation of the model...